# Emacs copy matching lines

Tags: emacs

In Emacs how can I easily copy all lines matching a particular regex?  Preferably highlighting the matching lines as I type.

`occur` gets partway there by coping them into a buffer, but it adds lots of extra stuff.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this:

```
(defun copy-lines-matching-re (re)
  "find all lines matching the regexp RE in the current buffer
putting the matching lines in a buffer named *matching*"
  (interactive "sRegexp to match: ")
  (let ((result-buffer (get-buffer-create "*matching*")))
    (with-current-buffer result-buffer 
      (erase-buffer))
    (save-match-data 
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (re-search-forward re nil t)
          (princ (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position) 
                                                 (line-beginning-position 2))
                 result-buffer))))
    (pop-to-buffer result-buffer)))
```

Comment: How do you do this so quickly?  It's also a completely different solution to the one I was expecting.  I was assuming it would use occur mode.  Thanks.

Comment: Um... it's a common type of thing to do.  There's really only 3 things going on here.  1) make a buffer, 2) search current buffer, 3) insert search result in the new buffer...

Comment: I've just googled this and found my own question from over 10 years ago.  I really should have put this in my `.emacs.d`

Answer (score 35):

As of Emacs 24, `occur` does in fact provide a simple solution:

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-s</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> `.*pattern.*` <kbd>RET</kbd>

When you use <kbd>C-u</kbd> on its own as the prefix argument, the matching portion of each line is inserted into the `*Occur*` buffer, without all the normal adornments.

Note that because only the part of the line matching the regexp is used (unlike a normal occur), you need the leading and trailing `.*` to ensure that you capture the entire line.

The details of how `occur` treats arguments are a little tricky, so read <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `occur` <kbd>RET</kbd> carefully if you want to know more.

Comment: Works like a charm! This should be the accepted answer now. :)

Comment: I disagree - I think `occur` should have an option that doesn't require a change in the pattern to match the entire line - it's basic purpose is finding matching lines, there should be a way to tell it not to use occur mode.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `keep-lines` to get what you want, copy them, and then undo.  For the opposite, there is also `flush-lines` to get rid of lines you don't want.

Comment: And how would one cut lines?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this happily for a long time:

```
    (defun occur-mode-clean-buffer ()
  "Removes all commentary from the *Occur* buffer, leaving the
unadorned lines."
  (interactive)
  (if (get-buffer "*Occur*")
      (save-excursion
        (set-buffer (get-buffer "*Occur*"))
        (fundamental-mode)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (toggle-read-only 0)
        (set-text-properties (point-min) (point-max) nil)
        (if (looking-at (rx bol (one-or-more digit)
                            (or " lines matching \""
                                " matches for \"")))
            (kill-line 1))
        (while (re-search-forward (rx bol
                                      (zero-or-more blank)
                                      (one-or-more digit)
                                      ":")
                                  (point-max)
                                  t)
          (replace-match "")
          (forward-line 1)))

    (message "There is no buffer named \"*Occur*\".")))

(define-key occur-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-x") 'occur-mode-clean-buffer)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install package `all`.  Then `M-x all` lets you edit all the lines in the buffer matching a regexp.  Instead of editing, you can just copy them too.