# Emacs: How to copy regex matches?

Tags: regex, emacs

I am simply trying to search/highlight text within a buffer using regex and copy it. I don't want the whole line, just the matches. Any ideas?

I have a large number of lines of text containing tags "[12345][09876]" and I want to regex 
copy all the tags out.

e.g.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit [12345][09876], 
sed diam nonummy [12345][123456] nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore 
magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud [54321][09876] 
exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip [23451][09656]
```

Comment: You mean kill or copy-region, not yank.

Comment: Yes, that's a confusing question. Could you either edit it to make sense, or else be more explicit about what you want to happen if you really did mean yank?

Comment: Apologies I didn't notice that when I posted. Sorry, I have edited it now.

Comment: @Mash, did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Use the occur command with universal-argument as Oleg comments below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, incremental search does not move the point position, so doing yank won't copy the match.

The easiest solution would probably be the following.

Define a function which copies a search match:

```
(defun copy-isearch-match ()
    (interactive)
    (copy-region-as-kill isearch-other-end (point)))
```

And add it to the search mode map

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "M-w") 'copy-isearch-match)
```

Then doing `M-x isearch-forward-regexp` you can press `M-w` to copy the match.

Comment: This appears to only highlight a single item which can be copied? Not sure how I would either select all matches, or move through each match?

Comment: @Mash see this question and the first answer. You can modify it to do what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289883/emacs-copy-matching-lines

Comment: Thanks, will look at this tonight.