# How do I search and copy in emacs?

Tags: emacs

My text follows the format:

```
HEADER hello
...
...

HEADER neighbour
...
...
...

HEADER test1
HEADER test2
```

I want to select all instances of `HEADER*\n` and copy them to a new document. So, the result would look like:

```
HEADER hello
HEADER neighbour
HEADER test1
HEADER test2
```

It doesn't matter if the spaces are preserved. Is this possible with standard emacs functionality?

Comment: Certainly a duplicate. sdasdadas: if you're running Emacs 24, I've just posted a very simple answer to that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be easier to copy the whole document to a new document, and then use `delete-non-matching-lines`.

```
M-x delete-non-matching-lines<RET> ^HEADER<RET>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not so trivial, but you can define such a function by yourself. Like the one here: [Emacs copy matching lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289883/emacs-copy-matching-lines)

Answer (score 2):

In the buffer, try

```
 C-u M-x occur RET ^HEADER.* RET
```

It should create a new buffer with just the output you want.  Then you can switch to that buffer and save it as a file, or mark it with `C-x h` and `M-w` and then yank it into a new buffer or whatever you need.

By the way, not a bare out-of-the-box answer, but for what it's worth, there is a nice library called all.el that gives Emacs the rather useful "all" command that was used on (if I remember correctly) xedit (an old mainframe text editor).  The library is [here](http://ftp.lip6.fr/pub/emacs/elisp-archive/incoming/all.el.gz) -- you might like that for this sort of thing too.