# Deleting lines which do not satisfy the regexp match

Tags: emacs

Suppose in Emacs I've opened a file, and I use C-y to paste new content at the end of the file.
I want to handle a case in which emacs deletes all the lines expect those lines for which I have use `M-x highlight-lines-matching-regexp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `M-x keep-lines` to delete lines not matching a regular expression. It also has an alias `M-x delete-non-matching-lines`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what If I have many regex for more than one lines?

Comment: `regex1\|regex2\|regex3`

Answer (score 0):

Barmar's answer might be enough (and [Emacs copy matching lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289883/emacs-copy-matching-lines) is probably also of interest), but here's a function which does (more or less*) what you asked:

```el
(defun my-keep-highlighted-lines ()
  "`keep-lines' matching any interactively-provided highlight regexps."
  (interactive)
  (require 'hi-lock)
  (keep-lines
   (mapconcat 'car hi-lock-interactive-patterns "\\|")))
```

(*) Obviously lines matching the regexp which have been added to the buffer *subsequent* to the highlighting will still be affected.

Also, this will use *all* the  interactive hi-lock patterns, so if you highlighted some phrases or arbitrary regexps, those lines will be kept as well. The 'line' regexps begin with `^.*` and end with `.*$`, so you could test for that in a custom mapconcat function if you wanted to.